# sendmail: complains about "Group writable directory" when that is not the case?

Tags: linux, email, sendmail

I can't start my `sendmail` service due to `Group writable directory` errors:

```
$ service sendmail start
Starting sendmail: 451 4.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 87: fileclass: cannot open '/etc/mail/local-host-names': Group writable directory
451 4.0.0 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf: line 596: fileclass: cannot open '/etc/mail/trusted-users': Group writable directory
                                                           [FAILED]
Starting sm-client: /etc/mail/submit.cf: line 552: fileclass: cannot open '/etc/mail/trusted-users': Group writable directory
                                                           [FAILED]
```

However, the permissions seem to be correct:

**/etc:**

```
$ ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x. 93 root root 4096 Oct 17 14:23 /etc
```

**/etc/mail:**

```
$ ls -ld /etc/mail
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Oct 19 16:43 /etc/mail
```

**/etc/mail/*:**

```
$ ls -ld /etc/mail/*
-rw------- 1 root root   469 May 20  2009 /etc/mail/access
-rw------- 1 root root 12288 May  5 18:11 /etc/mail/access.db
-rw------- 1 root root     0 Jun  8  2014 /etc/mail/aliasesdb-stamp
-rw------- 1 root root   233 Apr 12  2007 /etc/mail/domaintable
-rw------- 1 root root 12288 May  5 18:11 /etc/mail/domaintable.db
-rw------- 1 root root  5584 Nov 11  2010 /etc/mail/helpfile
-rw------- 1 root root    64 Apr 12  2007 /etc/mail/local-host-names
-rw------- 1 root root   997 Apr 12  2007 /etc/mail/mailertable
-rw------- 1 root root 12288 May  5 18:11 /etc/mail/mailertable.db
-rwx--x--x 1 root root  2700 May 20  2009 /etc/mail/make
-rw------- 1 root root    92 May 20  2009 /etc/mail/Makefile
-rw------- 1 root root 58439 Nov 11  2010 /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
-rw------- 1 root root  7202 May 20  2009 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc
-rw------- 1 root root 41521 Nov 11  2010 /etc/mail/submit.cf
-rw------- 1 root root   941 Nov 11  2010 /etc/mail/submit.mc
-rw------- 1 root root   127 Apr 12  2007 /etc/mail/trusted-users
-rw------- 1 root root  1847 Apr 12  2007 /etc/mail/virtusertable
-rw------- 1 root root 12288 May  5 18:11 /etc/mail/virtusertable.db
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Using sendmail, cute. What is the permissions of '/'?

Comment: Re your sendmail being cute comment - what would you recommend instead?

Comment: Personally prefer postfix for small-mid scale, but exim is quite popular. Some masochists choose qmail. :)

Comment: Why would you recommend *not* using sendmail?

Comment: Any services configuration file that needs to use m4 macros to function is not well thought out. It also has a long history of poor security.

Comment: If you want to make a quick answer re the root permissions I'd be happy to accept

Comment: +1 for postfix, and it installs a sendmail wrapper automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the permissions of '/'?